# Assign Member to Group via Powershell Graph API Call throws Request_BadRequest

Tags: office-365-developer, graph-api, azure-functions, access-token

Calling the following code:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[groupID]/members/`$ref"
$body = (@{'@odata.id'='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/[memberID]'} | ConvertTo-JSON)
Invoke-WebRequest -Method "POST" -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $retrievedToken"} -Body $body -UseBasicParsing -Verbose
```

Returns:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : { "error": { "code": "Request_BadRequest", "message": "No URI value was found for
an entity reference link. A single URI value was expected."
```

Obs.: The same request in Graph Explorer works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[groupID]/members/`$ref"
$body = (@{'@odata.id'='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/[MemberID]'} | ConvertTo-JSON)
Invoke-WebRequest -Method "POST" -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -Body $body
```